# Use laravel sanctum session-bases with next.js in sever side (like getServerSideProps metod)

Tags: laravel, session, axios, laravel-sanctum

I have laravel as backend and next.js as frontend of my website.
I use laravel sanctum for authentication.

My laravel app and next.js app are in the same host, then I can use session-base sanctum for authentication without use token.

After login there is no problem when I want to access the routes that are protected with middleware aute:sanctum in client side of next.js but in the server side always get error unauthenticated.

This is my axios config and my function for fetch data in next.js:

```
// axios instance
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'localhost:8000',
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  },
});

const onRequest = (config) => {
  if ((
    config.method == 'post' ||
    config.method == 'put' ||
    config.method == 'delete'
    /* other methods you want to add here */
  ) &&
    !Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')) {
    return setCSRFToken()
      .then(response => config);
  }
  return config;
}

const setCSRFToken = () => {
  return axiosInstance.get('api/v1/csrf-cookie');
}

// attach your interceptor
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(onRequest, null);

// fetch data:

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

    const { query, req } = context;

    const {
        page,
        search_term,
        nip,
        tableName
    } = query;

    try {
        const response = await ax.post(`api/v1/admin/${tableName}`, { page: page, search_term: search_term, nip: nip || 10 }, {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                Cookie: req.headers.cookie,
            }
        });

        return {
            props: {
                initItems: response.data.data,
                initMeta: response.data.meta,
                initSearchTerm: search_term || '',
                iniNip: nip || 10
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return {
            notFound: true,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to solve the same thing, did you make any progress on figuring this out?

Comment: I'd also be interested in any progress ...

Comment: In any case what I discovered: Using the cookies() method provided by next.js does *not* yield the correct XSRF-TOKEN which is required in order to submit a POST request to Laravel.